# Data chunk building logic in C++

Tags: c++

Well, it might be simple to some people but I could not managed to figure out any strong logic so far for the following data chunk building.

1. I have a chunk of char* or std::string data of size 1505 bytes
2. I need to cut this data into each max size of 500 bytes
3. Each piece of data should start with particular string set

Please see the below data chunk (i.e. Full data set of 1505 bytes)
Here I need to cut this data into 500 bytes of chunks (e.g. I will put this into a vector element) and each element text should start with [SampleSet]. So it can be possible that in one vector element I got two or more SampleSet but in other vector element I get only one [SampleSet].

Any clues how can I start off with this?

```
[SampleSet]
SampleTime=2014-08-13 T12:02:04
Data=Type:DataType|Value:0.11|Alert:false|Lead:II
Data=Type:DataType|Value:65|Alert:false
Data=Type:DataType|Value:95|Alert:false
Data=Type:DataType|Value:97.8|Alert:false|Channel:1
Data=Type:DataType|Value:90|Alert:false
Data=Type:DataType|Value:0.10|Alert:false|Lead:I
Data=Type:DataType|Value:0.20|Alert:true|Lead:II

[SampleSet]
SampleTime=2014-08-13 T12:05:09
Data=Type:DataType|Value:82|Alert:false
Data=Type:DataType|Value:98|Alert:true
Data=Type:DataType|Value:97.8|Alert:false|Channel:1
Data=Type:DataType|Value:97.8|Alert:false|Channel:1
Data=Type:DataType|Value:97.2|Alert:false|Channel:2
Data=Type:DataType|Value:31|Alert:false
Data=Type:DataType|Value:120|Alert:true
Data=Type:DataType|Value:95|Alert:true
Data=Type:DataType|Value:90|Alert:false
Data=Type:DataType|Value:0.10|Alert:false|Lead:I
Data=Type:DataType|Value:0.20|Alert:true|Lead:II

[SampleSet]
SampleTime=2014-08-13 T12:05:20
Data=Type:DataType|Value:82|Alert:false
Data=Type:DataType|Value:98|Alert:true
Data=Type:DataType|Value:31|Alert:false
Data=Type:DataType|Value:120|Alert:true
Data=Type:DataType|Value:95|Alert:true
Data=Type:DataType|Value:90|Alert:false
Data=Type:DataType|Value:0.10|Alert:false|Lead:I
Data=Type:DataType|Value:0.20|Alert:true|Lead:II

[SampleSet]
SampleTime=2014-08-13 T12:15:11
Data=Type:DataType|Value:82|Alert:false
Data=Type:DataType|Value:0.10|Alert:false|Lead:I
Data=Type:DataType|Value:0.20|Alert:true|Lead:II
```

Comment: Ehm just copy the string into a vector of strings 500 bytes at a time??? With a simple `for` loop?

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: I think that's not exactly what OP wants. He said he needs to have each chunk to start with `[SampleSet]`. So slicing it after every 500th byte is not going to give the correct result.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich: Right. Thats where I'm stuck.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich: Then he should indicate that in the question. I guess he needs to chop the input into blocks that always contain a whole number of `[SampleSet]`s but are of a maximum of 500 bytes. The point is that this problem statement needs to be _clear_ in a question!

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: He did.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich: Nope, not really.

Answer (score 2):

The most intuitive way of doing this would probably be to use [`std::string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) to find the position of all headers (=`"[SampleSet]"`) in your input string. Then you could cut this input string into tokens of which each contains exactly one sample set. You could then use these tokens to build 500-bytes-max-chunks. However if your sample sets are usually of a size much smaller than the chunk size, then you also call `find` very often.

A better approach would therefore be to use [`std::string::rfind`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rfind/) to begin searching backwards for a `[SampleSet]`-header at the right of a 500bytes-block-boundary. I.e. to find the first chunk start searching backwards for the header `[SampleSet]` at position `500`. The position you get from that (e.g. `467`) is the right boundary of the first chunk. To find the next chunk start searching backwards at `467+500` and so on. I hope the approach is clear. Here's a sample implementation:

```
std::string input; // your input data
std::vector<std::string> chunks;
std::string header("[SampleSet]");
std::string::size_type chunksize = 500; // size including header
std::string::size_type posL, posR = 0, posEnd = input.length()+1;

while(posR != posEnd) 
{
    posL = posR;
    if (posEnd-posL <= chunksize)
        posR = posEnd;
    else
        posR = input.rfind(header, posL+chunksize);

    if (posR-posL)
        chunks.push_back(input.substr(posL, posR-posL));
    else
    {
        std::string toobigsample(input.substr(posL, input.find(header,posL+1)-posL));
        std::cerr  << "Error: SampleSet to big to store in one chunk ("
                  << toobigsample.length() << " bytes):" << std::endl << std::endl
                  << toobigsample;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not bad. I'd throw an exception or write the error to `std::cerr`, though.

Comment: `std::cerr` it shall be.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich: Well, thanks for the code snippet. I just give it a quick try. It just added first SampleSet block to the vector and thats it. I think some more work has to be done inside the else block where you put some log. It exiting from there.

Comment: @hypheni: If you have a single sample set that is bigger than 500bytes, then it won't fit into a single chunk. That case must be handled somehow and here I chose to print an error message and then abort execution... You could of course handle it differently and without exiting... BTW: In your sample data the second sampleset is bigger than 500 bytes so my code aborts there...